# in a nested list how to test whether a given indexing sequence is valid in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a highly irregular nested list `myList` in mma, whenever I am given a integer sequence, such as `1,1,2,3,1` of any length, I want to know if

```
myList[[1,1,2,3,1]]
```

is valid; because if it is not, then I will get an error saying

```
Part::partw: part... does not exist
```

Thanks.

Comment: While this is a very legitimate question, you may still want to reconsider the design of your functions. If you need special checks that certain parts exist, this may mean that the problem, or at least your current formulation of it, does not lend itself nicely to the indexing-based approach. May be, rule-based or some other approach could eliminate the problem altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   Quiet[
       Check[mylist[[1, 1, 2, 3, 1]], Print[False], Part::partd], 
   Part::partd];
```

You can replace Print[False] for any other action ...

**Edit**

To check for both **partd** and **partw** messages the syntax is:

```
Quiet[Check[{{{1, 3}}, {2}}[[1, 4, 2, 3, 1]], 
    Print[False], {Part::partd, Part::partw}], 
   {Part::partd, Part::partw}];
```

HTH!

Comment: @belisarius: this still does not solve the problem I posed in general. See the following simple example: `Quiet[Check[{{{1, 3}}, {2}}[[1, 1, 2, 3, 1]], Print[False], 
   Part::partd], Part::partd];`

Comment: @Qiang Please re-check. It runs OK in my machine. It prints False, as an error indication

Comment: @bekusarius: what happened? If I copy/paste and run it, its behavior is correct. But if I just re-run what I had orginally, I alawys got `Part::partw: Part 4 of {{1,3}} does not exist. >>`. I looked over and over again and found the expressions are the same. why??? no previously defined variables here...

Comment: @Qiang It runs OK several times in a row my machine too. I'm using Mma 8. Perhaps a version conflict? Anyone else care to check this one?

Comment: @belisarius: Sorry I gave the wrong expression. Can you please try this one: `Quiet[Check[{{{1, 3}}, {2}}[[1, 4, 2, 3, 1]], Print[False], 
   Part::partd], Part::partd];`

Answer (score 3):

Coincidently this came up on MathGroup a few weeks ago. Below is a URL to what I believe was the last and best response (from Ray Koopman).

http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Jan/msg00326.html

It also has links to earlier posts in the same thread.

Daniel Lichtblau

Wolfram Research

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it.

```
Quiet[MemberQ[#, #[[1, 4, 2, 3, 1]], Infinity] &[{{{1, 3}}, {2}}]]
```

Returns False.

It will essentially return true or false after checking to see whether the element at that position (if it exists) is in the list.

```
Quiet[MemberQ[#, #[[1, 1, 2]], Infinity] &[{{{1, 3}}, {2}}]]
```

Returns True.

belisarius's answer will give more low level control though.